# Save millions of rows from CSV to Oracle DB Using Spring boot JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

On regular Basis another application dumps a CSV that contains more than 7-8 millions of rows. I have a cron job that loads the data from CSV ans saves the data into my oracle DB. Here's my code snippet

```
String line = "";
    int count = 0;
    LocalDate localDateTime;
    Instant from = Instant.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
    List<ItemizedBill> itemizedBills = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/u01/CDR_20210325.csv"));
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
            if (count >= 1) {
                String [] data= line.split("\\|");
                ItemizedBill customer = new ItemizedBill();
                customer.setEventType(data[0]);
                String date = data[1].substring(0,2);
                String month = data[1].substring(3,6);
                String year = data[1].substring(7,9);
                month = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(month);
                String modifiedDate = date + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                localDateTime = LocalDate.parse(modifiedDate, formatter);
                customer.setEventDate(localDateTime.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
                customer.setaPartyNumber(data[2]);
                customer.setbPartyNumber(data[3]);
                customer.setVolume(Long.valueOf(data[4]));
                customer.setMode(data[5]);
                if(data[6].contains("0")) { customer.setFnfNum("Other"); }
                else{ customer.setFnfNum("FNF Number"); }
                itemizedBills.add(customer);
            }
            count++;
        }
        itemizedBillRepository.saveAll(itemizedBills);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This feature works but takes a lot of time to process. How can I make it efficent and make this process faster?

Comment: If you want to run out of memory and have performance issues this is the way to go. Don't. Don't put stuff in a list and save all. Instead save individual items directly using `save` and after each x items (maybe 50 or 100) do a `entitymanager.flush` and `entitymanager.clear`. Performance will improve, for more tips see https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Another thing `String.split` is, relativly, slow. Instead use a `Pattern`, compile it and reuse that. That saves the overhead of each time needing to create the regexp classes. Saves memory as well and thus gc cycles.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you should do to your code.

1. `String.split`, while convenient, is relatively slow as it will recompile the regexp each time. Better to use `Pattern` and the `split` method on that to reduce overhead.
2. Use proper JPA batching strategies as explained in [this blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

First enable batch processing in your Spring `application.properties`. We will use a batch size of 50 (you will need to experiment on what is a proper batch-size for your case).

```java
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
```

Then directly save entities to the database and each 50 items do a `flush` and `clear`. This will flush the state to the database and clear the first level cache (which will prevent excessive dirty-checks).

With all the above your code should look something like this.

```
int count = 0;
Instant from = Instant.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile("\\|");
try {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/u01/CDR_20210325.csv"));
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        if (count >= 1) {
            String [] data= splitter.split(Line);
            ItemizedBill customer = new ItemizedBill();
            customer.setEventType(data[0]);
            String date = data[1].substring(0,2);
            String month = data[1].substring(3,6);
            String year = data[1].substring(7,9);
            month = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(month);
            String modifiedDate = date + "-" + month + "-" + year;
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(modifiedDate, formatter);
            customer.setEventDate(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            customer.setaPartyNumber(data[2]);
            customer.setbPartyNumber(data[3]);
            customer.setVolume(Long.valueOf(data[4]));
            customer.setMode(data[5]);
            if(data[6].contains("0")) { 
              customer.setFnfNum("Other"); 
            } else { 
              customer.setFnfNum("FNF Number"); 
            }
            itemizedBillRepository.save(customer);
        }
        count++;
        if ( (count % 50) == 0) {
          this.entityManager.flush(); // sync with database
          this.entityManager.clear(); // clear 1st level cache
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2 other optimizations you could do:

1. If your `volume` property is a `long` rather then a `Long` you should use `Long.parseLong(data[4]);` instead. It saves the `Long` creation and unboxing. With just 10 rows this might not be an issue, but with millions of rows, those milliseconds will add up.
2. Use `ddMMMyy` as the `DateTimeFormatter` and remove the `substring` parts in your code. Just do `LocalDate.parse(date[1].toUpperCase(), formatted)` to achieve the same result without the additional overhead of 5 additional `String` objects.

```java
int count = 0;
Instant from = Instant.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMyy");
Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile("\\|");
try {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/u01/CDR_20210325.csv"));
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        if (count >= 1) {
            String [] data= splitter.split(Line);
            ItemizedBill customer = new ItemizedBill();
            customer.setEventType(data[0]);
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(data[1].toUpperCase(), formatter);
            customer.setEventDate(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            customer.setaPartyNumber(data[2]);
            customer.setbPartyNumber(data[3]);
            customer.setVolume(Long.parseLong(data[4]));
            customer.setMode(data[5]);
            if(data[6].contains("0")) { 
              customer.setFnfNum("Other"); 
            } else { 
              customer.setFnfNum("FNF Number"); 
            }
            itemizedBillRepository.save(customer);
        }
        count++;
        if ( (count % 50) == 0) {
          this.entityManager.flush(); // sync with database
          this.entityManager.clear(); // clear 1st level cache
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. This means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use spring data batch insert.This links explains how to do : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts

Answer (score -1):

You can try streaming MySQL results using Java 8 Streams and Spring Data JPA. The below link explains it in details

http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html

Comment: The question is regarding to parse text and inserting it into the database. It is not about reading large results from the database.